# Laminate across multiple rooms, help!

Tags: doors, basement, laminate

I have to install laminate (actually it's click luxury vinyl planks) across multiple rooms in the basement (and some steps) without transition.  I have laid laminate in single rooms before, but this is something new and frankly a little overwhelming.

The bottom room is actually the main room, so I was going to start in the bottom-left corner running horizontally.  But there are so many openings to keep track of and it seems almost impossible to plan to avoid small board widths.

Even just starting along those two doorways.  Should I lay one full piece along the lower wall, and then fill in the three inch width across the door with its own cut piece?

Any advice is appreciated.

Mike.
[image: Basement]

Comment: Which way are the planks running? To keep your sanity, don't worry about narrow boards. They're going to happen no matter what. I'd set a line at the longest available point for your chosen direction, set another line parallel to that one near preferred starting point wall, and go to town.

Comment: Is it possible that you could use a nice threshold instead of coordinating between three rooms?  You can order in almost any shade, and the doorways don't look very wide.